# The proof of the abc conjecture

Tags: number-theory, hodge-theory

I recently heard that there was a workshop on Inter-universal Teichmuller theory in the Clay institute from 7-11 December 2015.This field of mathematics offers a potential proof of the abc conjecture.If anyone knows, what is the progress of the confirmation of Mochizuki's papers?

Comment: Brian Conrad recently wrote a good report about this.

Comment: If I am not wrong, this paper comes from before 7-11 December 2015   and uses an unorthodox math not many people understand .

Comment: Evidently there was some small amount of progress and much disappointment. This is a story that may take a decade to sort out. Some young researcher is going to have to bet their career on it and start at the beginning. But academic careers are not conducive to such an enterprise.

Comment: http://www.math.columbia.edu/~woit/wordpress/?p=8160#comments gives a number of links, plus plenty of links in the comments.

Comment: I asked this question on math overflow sometime ago, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/232087/have-there-been-any-updates-on-mochizukis-proposed-proof-of-the-abc-conjecture

Answer (score 3):

I attended a talk by Brian Conrad at my University recently regarding the $abc-$Conjecture. He informed us that the only people who have the faintest idea about Mochizuki's proof are Mochizuki himself and some of his closest understudies who claim its validity. Apparently they are completely unable to explain the work to outsiders. You may have already known that.

Here is a link to Conrad's own words: http://mathbabe.org/2015/12/15/notes-on-the-oxford-iut-workshop-by-brian-conrad/.

Comment: Fascinating how even the best algebraic geometers from the world cannot fully understand IUT even after 3 years of its creation.Shows you how much one can create by concentrating on one thing for 10 years.